# Hello World Android Program

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just built my goldfish android kernel. I wrote a hello world program and compiled using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. I used adb push to put the executable in /data/local of the emulated kernel. I was able to ssh into the emulated kernel using adb shell. When I cd into /data/local and ls the directory, I'm able to see the a.out which I had put using adb push. When I do #./a.out, I get the error ./a.out: not found.

Can some one help me on this.

Comment: Check the permissions for that directory

Comment: Permissions seems to be fine !

Comment: What's the output of `ldd ./a.out`?

Comment: `ls` worked, so the directory obviously had both `r` and `x` permissions for the user account in question.

Comment: how did you achieve this?  please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324772/cross-compiling-static-c-hello-world-for-android-using-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc/9359789#9359789

Answer (score 1):

I added the -static option during compilation worked. `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a missing library problem. I have met this problem before, my fix is below:

```
root@evab:~# ./a.out 
-sh: ./a.out: not found
root@evab:~# ls /lib /root
/lib:
libc.so.6

/root:
a.out
root@evab:~#
```

Then check which shared library is needed by the application:

```
leo@leo-VirtualBox:/opt/nfs/root$ arm-linux-readelf a.out -a |grep lib
    [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.3]
    0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
... ...
```

By the output, we can confirm that the `ld-linux.so.3` is missing, so copy `ld-linux.so.3` to target filesystem /lib directory:

```
root@evab:~# ./a.out 
test
root@evab:~# ls /lib /root
/lib:
ld-linux.so.3 libc.so.6

/root:
a.out
root@evab:~#
```