# Cross Compile helloworld for ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying a simple cross compile (cc) for an ARM-CORTEX-A9:
To keep things simple thats the c-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

The native compilation on the arm works fine and is started with `gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld` whereas the cross compile is started with `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld_cc`

***GCC Version:***

nativ: `gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf`

CC: `gcc version 4.6.3 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.03-79) Target: arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi`

***ABI from readelf:***

readelf-nativ: `OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.31`
readelf-cc: `OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.16`

***Linked libs*** - the cross compiled is statically linked so it shouldn't miss any libs:

```
root@localhost:/temp# ldd helloworld
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6ed8000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fce000)
root@localhost:/temp# ldd helloworld_cc
        not a dynamic executable
```

***The Problem:*** the native program runs fine, the cc always ends up with:

```
root@localhost:/tmp# ./helloworld_cc
-bash: ./helloworld_cc: No such file or directory
```

Any hints, hopefully, I have included enough information.

**edit**

Linking it static does the trick, but now the size of the file is huge (678kB (CC-static) vs. 4kB(native)? Why is it missing libs even if it says it is not dynamically linked? Similar question: [Cross compiling static C hello world for Android using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324772/cross-compiling-static-c-hello-world-for-android-using-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

```
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld_cc -static
```

Comment: Are you trying run ARM-CORTEX-A9 binary on x86 linux?

Comment: no it a Linaro/Ununtu running on the arm cortex a9 (xillinux on zedboard) http://xillybus.com/xillinux

Comment: ok. then check executable attribute on your binary.

Comment: i did chmod +x for both and doubled check graphicaly within the file browser properties

Comment: perhaps it is missed shared library on your target platform - here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716702/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-executing-a-binary and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/73491/no-such-file-or-directory-for-existing-executable

Comment: I don't think the simple example has any libs, i checked with ldd and it says for the cc version not dyn. linked. I also updated my gcc cc toolchain to match the gcc versin 4.6.3 of the target plattform, still getting the same error (edited question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ther was a missing link in the `lib` folder Linaro Ubuntu. It showed up with `readelf -a`

```
[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.3]
```

Putting the link `lib/ld-linux.so.3` to `lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.15.so`

and it works.

Thanks for the help Sergey

Comment: This post is old but I have a similar issue to yours, but can't solve it, so wondering if you could take a look at my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920945/cross-compile-qt-5-helloworld-app-for-armv7l