# gcc cross compile helloworld for ARM on Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, arm

I am using a Xilinx Zedboard. I cross compiled a c project that required the math.h library. When I run it on the Zedboard, I get a `./my_binary: not found` error. I am able to cross compile with the `-static` flag and get the binary to execute correctly. However, this is highly unhelpful because of the huge binary it generates.

There are a number of really similar questions. Namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324772/cross-compiling-static-c-hello-world-for-android-using-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935168/cross-compile-helloworld-for-arm). However both of them are cross compiling on Linux machines. The file system alone for the Linaro Compiler on Windows is significantly different so the answer to the 2nd question does not exactly fit. I also do not want to cross compile statically because the binary is way too big.

So if anyone has resolved this problem on Windows. I could really use some assistance. If it is a symbolic linking issue as suggested by the second question I linked to, I could use some help in figuring out what link is missing. As I said, the file structure for the Linaro compiler is very different from the Linux one mentioned in that post. So the links are not just cut-and-paste solutions. Furthermore, I poked around the `lib/` directory and didn't find the .so files by the name mentioned in that post either. (Though I am guessing that has to do with me running Windows not Linux.)

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try:

```
readelf -d my_binary
```

You may find all the dependencies. Copy all the dependencies to your arm machine.

Comment: ldd is neither available on windows or the arm machine

Comment: try readelf on your windows machine. such as `$ readelf -d t`

Comment: Ok, one dependency is `libm.so.6`. How do I "copy" that to my arm machine? How do I get it and where do I put it (directory-wise) on the arm machine?

Comment: search this file on your host machine, copy to your arm machine. put it under the same directory as the executable file

Comment: ok so if it were in the path for instance, that would be fine?

Comment: ok, could you change your answer to reflect the fact that windows does not have the ldd package so that I can accept it as being relevant?