# How to install glibc on top of a bare Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux

For some reason, I'm trying to make a minimal Linux system which only has essential components to run. I succeeded in installing BusyBox on my system, but I am having trouble installing glibc on top of it.

I just followed the instructions on this site:
http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_BusyBox_for_ARM

As per the instructions, all the libraries produced by glibc were put in the '/lib' directory. But when I tried to execute a dummy C program as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main { printf ("hello\n"); }
```

the system printed a "not found" message. Presumably this message means the system cannot find the glibc libraries.

How can I make the system find the libraries in the '/lib' directory by default? If the Linux kernel already finds libraries from there by default, what could have been wrong?

---

The above program was put in the '/scratch' directory with the name 'a.out'. I tried to execute it inside the directory by typing './a.out'. Here is the result of 'ls' in the root directory

```
bin  dev  etc  include  lib  linuxrc  proc  root sbin  scratch  sys  usr
```

As I mentioned, all the glibc libraries are in the '/lib' directory.

Comment: What exact commands did you type?

Comment: And what was the *exact unedited* system response?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it (notably by giving the *exact* commands that you tried)

Comment: The command was simply './a.out' in the directory where the above program (a.out) were. The unedited system also printed "not found" :(

Comment: @GwangmuLee How/where did you compile your example program ? Perhaps you're using a compiler toolchain that links to some other standard C library, and not glibc ? Also note that glibc needs a slew of other things as well, at the very least ld-linux.so.2

Comment: @nos Oh I got that. I compiled the example on my host system, so it might have been tried to link to some other libc library. It is not as easy as I expected to install libc on top of Linux kernel. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, do a `readelf -a ./a.out | grep interpreter` and see what it says, is that file on your target ?

Comment: [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.3] Actually I checked 'readelf -d a.out' but it didn't show 'ld-linux.so.3'. What's 'ld-linux.so.3' and how can I load it on my kernel? Any article I can refer would be great help for me.

Comment: Your edited question is still not precise enough.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Oops sorry :(. Actually because there are lots of things I could not understand, I had no idea what to write on my question.

Comment: You might see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935168/cross-compile-helloworld-for-arm

Answer (score 1):

The `not found` message is certainly not due to lack of `libc` (what *exact* commands did you type to get that?). Perhaps you have some [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) issue, and your shell (probably BusyBox) gave you that? Try typing the entire path of your executable.... 
If [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) or [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) are available, you might want to use them.

You apparently want to undertake something very similar to [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

You might be interested in [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) (it is an alternative to GNU `glibc`, perhaps slightly easier to build)

Stricto sensu, you cannot have a running system with just a bare Linux kernel, it needs at least some initial program (e.g. `/sbin/init`, or `/bin/sh`, or whatever you give thru `init=` thru [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) or some other loader to your kernel)

BTW, your issue is certainly *not a kernel issue*, it could be some [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) one (e.g. related to [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) or whatever "interpreter" is mentioned in your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable, see [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)). When the kernel fails to [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) some file, it won't output on *stderr*, is is giving error notice thru [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (as specified by the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface))

Use [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) & [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) (perhaps the cross-build variants of them) on your executable to understand what is inside it.

I recommend to read more about [Linux programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) before undertaking such a route.

Comment: I tried to type the absolute path of 'a.out', but it didn't work out :(. For you information, the boot was successful on QEMU with '/sbin/init'.

Comment: Typically though, such a "not found" message is due to the lack of a dynamic linker, which would be typical if the program is compiled with a toolchain linking to another libc that isn't installed on the target, or the target is missing the dynamic linker that needs to match its libc.

Comment: I also considered to refer Linux From Scratch, but I found it is too much for now to follow the entire instructions. Thanks for the recommendation :)