# Building Android app for running PHP and MySQL on Android Tablet

Tags: php, android, mysql, linux, cross-compiling

I want to run PHP + MySQL server on my Android Device. People seem to suggest applications like [KSWeb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&hl=en) and [Bit Web](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&hl=en).

Other solutions suggested are that I install an [application that allows me to run Linux on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en). This requires the Android Device to be rooted. :(

I don't want to use any other application for this. So I would like to build an application  similar to [KSWeb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&hl=en) myself. I have searched around for how to start building such application but it has not helped so far. Any guidance on how to go about this?

I mean how is it possible for KSWeb to build something like this, without root. :O

Any guidance on how to go about building this application would be very helpful.

Somewhere I was told to get the binaries compiled for ARMv6, but I don't know how to start.

Can [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) be of any use to me?

Please Help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am currently maintaining [free and open source web server](http://github.com/droidphp) solution stack package, consisting mainly of the Lighttptd HTTP Server, MySQL database, PHP programming languages. It is still at beta stage.

It can give you a basic idea about how to develop this type of stuffs in android.

Yes, its true binaries must compiled for ARM CPU in order make file executable.

And you can use NDK  but i recommend you to go with alternatives like [CodeSourcery](http://www.codesourcery.com/gnu_toolchains/) or [Linaro](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/)

Here some starter tutorial for cross compiling Linux program to ARM

- [ARM cross-compiling](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-arm-cross-compiling-howto.html)
- [Cross compiling static C hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324772/cross-compiling-static-c-hello-world-for-android-using-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

Anyway you can read this article how i cross compile for DroidPHP

- [Cross Compiling for DroidPHP](https://github.com/DroidPHP/DroidPHP/blob/master/docs/Compiling.md)

Comment: Thanks. This looks very similar to what I need. I will study this and get back to you.

Comment: Hey Shushant.. Can you explain me the steps to compile PHP, MySQL and Apache into Android? Compiling from source looks to be big work. I remember building Apache, PHP and MySQL on FreeBSD, it took several hours! :O

I would be happy if you can explain the steps for compilation. :D

Comment: compiling php along with commonly required extension is nightmare you will need to cross compile extension separately. if you need help in cross compiling create an new question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for a quick revert. I will learn more about cross compiling extension separately. Can you share with me the steps for compiling PHP in general on Android.

Comment: Sorry Shushant for being a pain.. Do u have some link(s) for a tutorial on this. The above line is not much comprehensible for me.

Comment: Shushant.. I don't know if this is a bug with DroidPHP or no. But when I use `getRunningServices` I always get a service by the name of `com.github.DroidPHP.ServerService`. I get this even if the server is not running. I guess you need to add `stopService` in the `btn_stopServer.setOnClickListener` in the `HomeActivity.java` .

Comment: I am using the cross compiled PHP, Lighttpd from your application to run the server on my android tablet. I am able to run these 2 successfully. But I am having issues running MySQL.. I need your help on this. Can you share your email address or something where we can talk?

Answer (score 6):

here is some articles regarding cross compiling PHP, Nginx, Lighttpd on arm6

### Cross compiling PHP

- [Cross Compile PHP 5.3.3 to ARM](http://tiebing.blogspot.in/2010/08/cross-compile-php-533-to-arm.html)
- [Error while compiling PHP for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321366/error-while-compiling-php-for-arm) (not reverent but helpful)
- [starting with php cross compile](http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/1272)
- [Cross Compile Lighttpd + PHP + MySQL for ARM (2)](http://tw.myblog.yahoo.com/stevegigijoe/article?mid=317&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed:%20BeagleBoard%20%28BeagleBoard.org%29) (in Chinese but translate it to English)

### Cross compling LIghttpd

- [lighttpd cross compiling](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/3/topics/1070)
- [Cross compiling for ARM9 doesn't work](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/1834)

### Cross compiling Nginx

- [Nginx CMake](https://github.com/changyy/nginx-cmake)

Answer (score 1):

I am New to android but something sounds wrong about all this.php is a server side scripting language. Now you are going to run around from hot spot to hot spot hosting I guess a web service backed by a mysql database. Do you have a static ip? Mysql is an excellent choice for a low end dbms if sqlite was not already built into droid. Like I said I am New and it's probably me but this just sounds wrong.
From the answers I see someone talking about compiling php which would make it no longer script.

Comment: Actually we are going to run PHP+MySQL server on the tablet. That tablet won't be connected to Internet in general. The current application that I have runs over internet or LAN using Soap API. So I want to configure PHP + MySQL server on the tablet itself, so that there is not need to set up a different server on the LAN.

Comment: All androids have sqlite built-in.

Comment: if you want to make server access over world wide consider using dynamic dns service like freedns.afraid.org

Comment: @Shushant.. No I won't make server access over world wide. Server would just be used as localhost or at max in LAN.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to use something other than PHP/Mysql, Python may be a good option. You can listen to sockets and send info through Python, which is supported through SL4A app.

Apparently CherryPy works on Android: http://www.defuze.org/archives/228-running-cherrypy-on-android-with-sl4a.html

There's Django and probably others, but those may be more complex to set up.

Comment: If I was to write a new application, then I would rather write a native android application, why would I go the client-server way? :P