# method for implementing PHP on android

Tags: java, php, android

ive been looking for an alternative to programming in android,

I know php very well..

ive been thinking why there is not a packaging system

that combines

php executable, 
a browser, embedded in a main program in java, 
and php scripts,

to make a apk program,

that could be put in play market, downloaded, installed and run locally?

the java shell would have a browser window,
it would run the php script with the php executable,
show the results directly in the browser window, html returned from the php
any clicks or input would be collected and sent to the php script again, 
and the html result shown again in the browser,

no need for learning interface commands or java or other languages,
all you would need is php and html and you can write full programs

even graphical things with gd library..

have you heard of such a system? is there a reason why it cant be done crossplatform?
(Perhaps the php executable needs to be compiled differently for different devices)

thanks

Comment: I also wanted something like this, however I settled on Bit Web Server for Android (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&hl=en).  This gives you LIGHTTPD, PHP, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin. So you can develop a web application as normal. However it is NOT an app, it simply allows you to create a web application which you have to view through the browser, not ideal and a bit clunky but it did the job for my needs.

Comment: thanks, but my issue is I want to make and distribute programs written in php, preferably using the market.
in earlier years a friend of mine did a hack on a php executable and embedded the source of my script into the executable and compiled it, then my program was as an exe file, though without the browser parts..

Comment: Hope you figure out a way as I would be interested in this also.

Comment: I was expecting it to have been done already

Answer (score 0):

There is already PhoneGap for that. But i'd advice you learn native language for platform.
All this webapp packed as application looks like cheapo chinese replicas of normal apps.

Comment: thanks, but i dislike all three languages involved (html5 css javascript) :)
im asking for a method of using and distributing php scripts as programs via the market

Comment: You can build (static) PHP binary then run it from your application with scripts you like. Search how to build in binary executable to APK, there is plenty of examples.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: First you start with crosscompiling PHP for android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028072/building-android-app-for-running-php-and-mysql-on-android-tablet

Comment: will I need to compile different for each architecture?
and then write a java program with browser window, run the script, give parameters, take result show on browser, then intercept clicks and call the php script with new parameters?

Comment: In general answer is Yes to all of your questions. There is at least two platforms to build to - ARM and x86. Then it is up to you how to use PHP. if you run php in server mode (since 5.4) it may be enough to work directly via webview. Otherwise you'll need to make some interface to pass php scripts to interpreter. maybe by using stdin and stdout.

Comment: hi again, is there already a class/function for displaying/rendering html code in a window in a java program? like a built in browser window? I cant imagine everyone writing their own browser renderer.. what is this thing called?